# Classify the coordinate data

Tags: data-mining, algorithms

I'd like to classify the data on coordinate.

Here are 2 example data.

data1 = [(1,1), (2,2), **(3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 3)**, (6, 0)]

data2 = [(1,1), (2,2), **(3, 10), (4, 9), (5, 10)**, (6, 0)]

The bold part have the same wave in above data.

The length are all different in my data set.

Is there any way that I can find the similar wave in many data like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Calcualte distance?

Distance = data2 - data1 = [(1,**0**), (2,**0**), *(3, **7**), (4, **7**), (5, **7**)*, (6, **0**)]

And what will you treat as *the same wave*?

Any three (or more) nearby points that have the same distance...

Comment: Maybe we can calculate the distance of slope.